# How to in dart "omit" property from implemented interface

Tags: dart

In Typescript you can omit certain properties e.g.

```
type TodoInfo = Omit<Todo, "completed" | "createdAt">;
```

I am not able to find this feature in dart.
Reason is, I have a users class, where I need to remove `id` when adding to the DB.

```
abstract class Users {
 int id;
 String username;
 String password;
}
```

Comment: You can't get a list of properties at runtime anyway, so whatever code you are using to push this into a DB should just ignore id.  If you are using some builder, there will be ways to configure that builder as to the relevant fields.

Comment: I see, so this is not doable. thanks, @RandalSchwartz

Comment: It's doable, just not that syntax.